# how to do the sort function with specific value when the page load i dont know much about coding

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, web-applications, tablesorter

this is all data the page loads

[image]

this is what i want data to show when page load

[image]

And here is a picture of the current code:

[image]

I'm sure this is the sort function base on the select but i want to just sort base on a value without selection my goal to show data only for specific people base login name

my goal is to make multi level login page from google app script i dont know alot about java html i just try to edit code online it work so far but sort for specific data is where i stuck the program work fine i just want to add option that only data for specific login user

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sort+function+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please post CODE, NOT pictures of code

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The script gets the values of column with index 1 and sorts the unique values before creating a select

Comment: this is a part javascript for sort table base on select option value but i want to make another one with a specific value like 'blue' or 'country' no need to select and load when the page start. that what i think it has something to do with this part

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. [edit] your question, show some input and expected output/result and what you tried to do that failed

Comment: i try to add some image hope you understand

Comment: Lol. You expect us to understand enough Vietnamese to see what you filtered? Please 1. POST CODE instead of pictures of code. 2. Post an explanation with some example readable data that shows how you want to filter or sort or whatever the data in column 1 (whatever that might be)

Comment: You want to only show `ឯកសារចូល` and `ឯកសារចេញ`? Then filter on those words